# Parse out specific characters from java string

Tags: java

I have been trying to drop specific values from a String holding JDBC query results and column metadata.  The format of the output is:

```
[{I_Col1=someValue1, I_Col2=someVal2}, {I_Col3=someVal3}]
```

I am trying to get it into the following format:

```
I_Col1=someValue1, I_Col2=someVal2, I_Col3=someVal3
```

I have tried just dropping everything before the "=", but some of the "someVal" data has "=" in them.  Is there any efficient way to solve this issue?

below is the code I used:

```
for(int i = 0; i < finalResult.size(); i+=modval) { 
  String resulttemp = finalResult.get(i).toString();
  String [] parts = resulttemp.split(",");

  //below is only for
  for(int z = 0; z < columnHeaders.size(); z++) {
    String replaced ="";
    replaced = parts[z].replace("*=", "");
    System.out.println("Replaced: " + replaced);
  }
}
```

Comment: "I have tried..." Please show us :)

Comment: Where's the code you tried?!

Comment: @user7294900 You mean `.replace` not `replaceAll` replaceall is intended to be used with regexes

Comment: @fill͡pant͡ and a replacement is needed. `replace('[', '').replace('{', '')`

Comment: @Michael no objections to that, my objection is the use of `replaceAll` instead of `replace` because acording to the docs it is intended for regular expressions and the above instance was not using a regular expression ;)
 Also replacement is not _needed_ you could match rather than replace as i mention in my answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need *any* splitting here!

You can use [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and the power of regular expressions to simply **replace** *all* occurrences of those unwanted characters, like in:

```
someString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\{\\}", "")
```

When you apply that to your strings, the resulting string should exactly look like required.

Comment: A bit too harsh to downvote maybe, but in your case wouldn't you just replace all occurrences of the string "[]{}" with an empty string and not the individual characters without the pipe to act as an OR?

Comment: I don't think this is [a valid regex](https://regex101.com/r/k2H5A1/1).

Comment: Should be `someString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "")`

Comment: The only reason I was splitting, is because I wanted each value in a separate String anyway.  That had nothing to do with me trying to remove special characters

Comment: @dgelinas21 If you use the matching approach i mentioned above, group(1) returns a string matching _one_ occurance which you could use as a "seperate string" therefore no spliting required unlike replacing. :Δ

Comment: Exactly as @GhostCat said the chosen solution is not optimal... I tried pointing that out in the comments earlier _before_ it was even accepted and i also pointed it out when a similar solution was sugested in the comments of the main post however i think im ignored.
Well it looks like the OP values code simplicity and shortness instead of runtime efficiency... :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to replace the square and curly brackets like this `[\[\]{}]`

For example:

```
String s = "[{I_Col1=someValue1, I_Col2=someVal2}, {I_Col3=someVal3}]";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]{}]", ""));
```

That would produce the following output:

```
I_Col1=someValue1, I_Col2=someVal2, I_Col3=someVal3
```

which is what you expect in your post.

A better approach however might be to match instead of replace if you know the character set that will be in the position of 'someValue'. Then you can design a regex that will match this perticular string in such a way that no matter what seperates `I_Col1=someValue1` from the rest of the String, you will be able to extract it :-)

**EDIT:**
With regards to the matching approach, given that the value following `I_Col1=` consists of characters from `a-z` and `_` (regardless of the case) you could use this pattern: `(I_Col\d=\w+),?`

For example:

```
String s = "[{I_Col1=someValue1, I_Col2=someVal2}, {I_Col3=someVal3}]";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(I_Col\\d=\\w+),?").matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

This will produce:

```
I_Col1=someValue1
I_Col2=someVal2
I_Col3=someVal3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do four calls to `replaceAll` on the string.

```
String query = "[{I_Col1=someValue1, I_Col2=someVal2}, {I_Col3=someVal3}]"
String queryWithoutBracesAndBrackets = query.replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\[", "")
```

Or you could use a regexp if you want the code to be more understandable.

```
String query = "[{I_Col1=someValue1, I_Col2=someVal2}, {I_Col3=someVal3}]"
queryWithoutBracesAndBrackets = query.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\{|\\}", "")
```